# How to define local variable to a function after creating it

Tags: javascript, function, scope, local-variables, declare

- I wonder if there's a way to define local variable to a function after declaring it for example if i have the following function

```
function x() { return t;}
```

how can i define `t` as local variable by default to define local variable you should declaring it inside it's function like

```
function x() {var t = 123; return t;}
```

but my question is there's a way to define `t` as local variable to the first function then execute it something like

```
function x() { return t }
var y = x.define(var t = 123);
y();
```

- i hope someone help me to do something like that in local scope of the function x

Comment: Not possible... Functions should be well defined at their creation.

Comment: Then there's no way to add variable to the local scope of function x or even add new scope to allow him access local variables of another function ?

Comment: That's what I mean: there is no way to add variables to the local scope of function `x`. You can only influence function `x` via non-local variable changes. So in your example, `t` would be a global variable. But your question was about local, so the answer is: not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, functions are first-class citizens. It can be passed as a parameter or returned as a value. As you say, in order to change the value inside a function, you need to create a closure based on the above.

```js
function generate(t) {
  return function() {
    return t+2;
  };
}

const a = generate(1);
const b = generate(2);

a(); // return 3;
b(); // return 4;
```

Comment: if you don't want to make new function by call generate(), then you can using IIFE(Immediately-invoked function expression).

generate(1)(); //return 3;
generate(2)(); //return 4;

Comment: That's not want i need - i want to define new closure which isn't defined when creating the function to the local scope of the function then call it to execute normally without getting Uncaught Error t isn't defined

Answer (score 0):

Factory function?

```
// return a new function with t as a local variable.
const makeY = t => {
    // t is local, return new function with t.
    return () => t;
}
const y = makeY(123);
y(); //returns 123
```

Or object notation with clone function, according to the feedback in JSX's comment.

```
const defaultVars = {t:123};

function x(vars = defaultVars) {
   // private not accessible from global scope
   const privateVars = {...vars};
   this.set = function(varname, value) {
       privateVars[varname] = value;
   }
   this.clone = function() {
        // copy private variables
        return new x({...privateVars});
   }
   this.run = function() {
      return privateVars.t;
   }
}
const y = new x();
y.run() // 123
y.set('t', 1337);
y.run() // 1337
const z = y.clone(); // copy y
z.run() // 1337
z.set('t', 1349);
z.run() // 1349
y.run() // still 1337
```

Comment: Maybe the example that i put near of your answer but i don't want to pass it as argument i want to define a local variable to local scope of function x so when check the global object `window` don't find it and when calling the function it's find it and execute the code but the problem here is that i want to define the local variable after creating the function

Comment: I am not sure, but it sounds like what you are trying to do is a class with private variables with public setter/getter? e.g. clone ``x`` into ``y`` to reuse ``x`` object state? 
Or do you have a better use case? Or is your question more general how the JS-scope works?

Answer (score -1):

here is shortest solution:

**AS SHORT AS POSSIBLE**

```
const x = t => t;

const y = () => x(123);

y(); //returns 123
```

**EASIER TO UNDERSTAND**

```
function x(t) {
   return t;
}

function y() {
   return t(123);
}

y(); //returns 123
```

Only thing I cannot understand is, why would you do that?
You can call `t()` with parameter without needing to declare `y()` function, it is redundant.

Comment: I don't want it as argument i want it as local variable to function x

Comment: It is not possible. The only way is to make global variable which will be visible inside of ```x```. Can you explain whole problem? Maybe we could find better solution :)

Answer (score -1):

If you're ok with changing the function:

```js
function x() { 
 return x.t
}

function y() {
 x.t = 123
 return x()
}

function z() {
 x.t = 'abc'
 return x()
}


console.log(y())
console.log(z())
```

An approach that gets `t` defined inside `y`. It's not exactly the same as accessing to the original closure but depending on your purpose it can fit. Notice that now x doesn't need to be global, you can pass whatever the function (or create in on the fly) and it will still work

```js
function x() { 
  return t
}
function y(cb) {
   this.t = 123
   const toCall = cb.call(this)
   delete this.t
   return toCall
}
console.log(y(x))

console.log(y( () => `t is ${t}`))
```

Comment: I don't need any global variables i want to add a variable to the local scope of a function after creating it and they said that's not possible

Comment: no global variables were used here, the first `t` is just to show a before&after effect

Comment: `t` in here is global variable and `x.t` i don't want to use the variable as property i want it as local variable to call him with it's name directly

Comment: edited to let you see that no global variables are needed.

Comment: I know you are trying to help me and i'm appreciated that but really that's not what i want and also this editation not provide any help because x in here's is global function which everything in the script can access it and all you done here is just you set property to that global function then when you call that property then call the function the changes will be added that's like declaring global variable then change it's value what i mean in here you don't add anything deferant  which can help answer my question

Comment: that's not what i need what i need is to add new variable to the local scope of function x or add new scope to function x to allow him to access  local functions, variables (Closures) of another function and they said that's not possible